# Saving AS3 data to XML file

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a serious of games swf's loading externally from a main menu swf.

What I'm trying to do is take name of the player which they input into textfield and sent it to the XML file. After this at the end of each game I want to send the time it took to complete also to the XML file.

The problem I have is I don't know to to create a new user inside the XML file and then replace the default time of 00:00:00 with the time that the player has set.

NameTextField is the name of the textfield.

Hourtext, Minutetext and Secondtext are the names of the timer. (They are ordered like Hourtext ':' Minutetext ':' Secondtext.

AS3 code inside Flash MainMenu.swf

```
var XMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var Bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var FileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();

XMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, XMLLoaded );
XMLLoader.load( new URLRequest("GameTimes.xml"));

function XMLLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    var XMLDoc:XML = new XML( e.target.data );
    //trace( XMLDoc.Users.User.(@Name == "Name01").Game.(@Title == "Game01"));
}
```

XML code inside GameTimes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <Company>
        <Users>
            <User Name = "Name01">
                <Game Title = "Game01">00:00:00</Game>
                <Game Title = "Game02">00:00:00</Game>
                <Game Title = "Game03">00:00:00</Game>
                <Game Title = "Game04">00:00:00</Game>
                <Game Title = "Game05">00:00:00</Game>
                <Game Title = "Game06">00:00:00</Game>
                <Game Title = "Game07">00:00:00</Game>
                <Game Title = "Game08">00:00:00</Game>
            </User>
            <User Name = "Name02">
                <Game Title = "Game01">00:00:00</Game>
                <Game Title = "Game02">00:00:00</Game>
                <Game Title = "Game03">00:00:00</Game>
                <Game Title = "Game04">00:00:00</Game>
                <Game Title = "Game05">00:00:00</Game>
                <Game Title = "Game06">00:00:00</Game>
                <Game Title = "Game07">00:00:00</Game>
                <Game Title = "Game08">00:00:00</Game>
            </User>
        </Users>
    </Company>
```

Thanks for any help :)

Edit:

Code for when submit button (submit name entered to textfield)

```
Cmpany.Users.appendChild("User Name = " NameTextField.text );
trace( XMLDoc.Users.appendChild(HourText.text));
```

Error I'm getting

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable TCMText is not defined.
```

Comment: First off, when using appendChild, you need to specify the whole XML tag as such, i.e. xml.appendChild(<User name="{NameTextField.text}"></User>); And what is TCMText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new XML node (your user) works with appendChild.

So yourXML.company.users.appendChild(your new user node).

Comment: If more than 2 players played the game what would happen then as there wouldn't be anything to append? I need a way of inserting more uses into the XML file so that when the 3rd person plays the game  <User Name = "Name03"> is created and the times are added from there

Comment: With company.users.appendChild( your new user ) you append a new user to the 'Users' tag. You shouldn't pre-populate your XML file with n users if you don't know how many users you'll end up with. The same applies for the games a user played. Start with an empty XML like Company-Users and add users and their games at runtime (with appendChild that is).

Comment: With: yourXML.company.users.appendChild(your new user node). is the yourXML what I've called XMLDoc in the code above or something else?

Comment: Sorry, should have given my answer with your variable names, yes that would be XMLDoc. Just for reference, try to adhere to global naming conventions, such as starting variables names with a lower case.

Comment: Hey, am getting a few errors with this code will edit my original post with the errors in a few mins